# Issue regarding Java Compilation in Hudson

Tags: java, compiler-construction, hudson

Let say I have a Transformation class that extending a CommonDomain class.

and I create a DaoUtil just to inserting a default parameter for insert.

```
public static void populateValuesForInsert(CommonDomain domain, Long userId)
{
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    domain.setCreatedBy(userId);
    domain.setCreatedDate(today);
    domain.setUpdatedBy(userId);
    domain.setUpdatedDate(today);
}

public class Transformation  extends CommonDomain
{
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = -2800564185309854734L;
    private Long id;
    private Long scenarioType;
    private String description;
    //.... get set here ... 

}

public class CommonDomain implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final Integer DEFAULT_BASELINE_ID = 0;

    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_WITH_TIME = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    public long maxRowCount;
    private String roleName;
        private Date createdDate;
    private Date updatedDate;   
        private Long createdBy;
    private Long updatedBy;   
        //..get set here
}
```

when I run the JUnit Testing, it's working perfectly in local.
However running the testing in Hudson resulting this error:

```
populateValuesForInsert(com.domain.CommonDomain,java.lang.Long) in 
com.utils.DaoUtil
cannot be applied to (com.domain.Transformation,java.lang.Long)
```

I use JDK 1.5.0_14 in my Local and JDK 1.5.0_21 in my Hudson.

Any idea why does this error happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Hudson's internals, but maybe there's some sort of cache which holds an old version of some of the class files.

Comment: That was my first quess. Deleting workspace and clearing the dependencies should fix that,but failed. Let me check again...

Comment: cache. after the weekend the issue dissapeared by itself.